# Customize jQuery UI dialog style

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, dialog

I have this dialog:

```
var dialog1 = $('<div>').dialog({ 
    autoOpen: false, 
    modal: true,
    closeText: null,
    hide: "scale",
    show:"fade",
    height: 'auto',
    width: 450,
    dialogClass:"edialog"
});
```

when I want to customize style,inline style overrides my style:

[image: overrriding]

How can I force dialog to use my style without using `!important` or edit generated inline style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't.  Inline has the highest precedence over the selector chain.  The **only** way to override it, that I know of, is to modify the DOM of the element or use `!important`.

I would say if they went through the trouble of defining the styles inline, it is for a good reason and probably shouldn't be modified.

---

Here would be the difference between using `!important` and changing the inline style with jQuery:

**jQuery:**
`$(".ui-dialog").css({ "position" : "fixed", "top" : "50%" });`

**css:**
`.ui-dialog { position: fixed !important; top: 50% !important; }`

**Dialog Options (Barmar's comment):**

`$(".my-form").dialog({ position: { my: "top", at: "top" } });`

It depends on how you feel and want to manage your source code.  CSS seems like a easier and more elegant solution to me if you can't do it through the properties the Dialog object exposes.

Comment: Inline styles are used for styles that can be specified as options, like `width: 450`, so that the options will take precedence over CSS.

Comment: Is there any way to edit generated inline style from jQuery UI?

Comment: @majidgeek You can if you select the element and work with the style through javascript.  Is that really better than using `!important`, well that is a design consideration you will have to make, but I say it isn't in most cases.

Comment: @majidgeek See updated post for the examples on using css and js as a solution.

Comment: @majidgeek Barmar makes a good point, jQuery Dialog does offer a position property when creating your dialog object which will allow you to choose where it is positioned.  I would recommend looking over the [Dialog API](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position) again to see if you can resolve this in another way.

Answer (score 0):

1. You find custom dialog in CSS
2. The example, if you want edit width of dialog, only add "!important" after width:

   .ui-dialog { position: relative; padding: .2em; width: 500px !important;}